# I am working on an Application which closes after the splash screen and the next activity was not loaded

Tags: java, android

i am working on a filter app and have created a splash screen and one other activity named 'ControlActivity' but as soon as the splash screen disappears the app closes without loading the 'ControlActivity'.
Also it does not gives any error closing the app.

**The code for Main Activity is:-**

```
package com.example.harsh.filters;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ControlActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        },1000);

    }
}
```

**The XML code for the ControlActivity:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".ControlActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/centerImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="315dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/img1"
        tools:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        tools:padding="16dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/centerImageView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:layout_below="@+id/centerImageView"
        tools:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/uncheck" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/check" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="147dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        tools:layout_below="@+id/controlLinearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/effect1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/effect2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/effect3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/effect4" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

**The ControlActivity:-**

package com.example.harsh.filters;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class ControlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control);



    }

}
```

**Manifest:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.harsh.filters">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ControlActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_control"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me out and thanks.

Comment: This looks fine, can you setup a simple test project on git for me to take a look?

Comment: Please post your logcat